# Separate Workplaces in Windows 10

Tags: windows, user-accounts, virtual-desktop

I'm looking for a way to seperate my work and home desktops on windows without a minute long switch each time I move back and forth. That is, seperate desktop folders, seperate open windows and seperate taskbars. I used to use Dexpot, but the newest insider builds appear to have killed it. I had hoped virtual desktops might be able to accommodate that, but no luck. Therefore, it seems like I'm stuck using seperate user accounts- except switching user accounts is excruciating. Start Menu - User - Select User - Wait for spinning circle - Click Log in - Wait for spinning circle - load into new desktop. Then, the same thing in reverse to switch back, but with the addition of entering a password.

Is there any way to get two seperate workplaces without such a painful process to move between them?

Comment: A faster but initially more expensive way is to get another Windows 10 License and set up a Windows 10 Virtual Machine. Hyper-V comes free with Windows 10; I prefer VMware Workstation. Once done, you have two machines: 1 work, 1 personal that you can switch between instantly.

Comment: Doesn't continuously running a VM absolutely decimate your computer's resources? Or is there some clever trick for it?

Comment: Nope. I have a machine with Host and 3 Virtual Machines running all the time. Because of lockdown, I set my Battery Threshold to 80% and leave the machine on all the time. Lots of resources for anything I wish.

Answer (score 0):

I have sixteen Windows 10 Task View Virtual Desktops, and switching between them takes less than a second.

Instead of placing desktop items directly on the desktop, you could put home-specific and work-specific items in separate folders with Medium Size Icons, and leave one of those folders open on each virtual desktop.  It's not convenient to arrange the folder vertically next to the desktop icons, because subsequent Explorer windows open with the same size.  However, you can easily Alt-Tab to the folder (I find my desktop shortcuts are usually covered by some other window, which is also not convenient).

As you discovered, there is no provision for separate toolbars.  However, you can restrict the taskbar to show only icons for windows that are open on the current desktop (in addition to pinned icons).  I use custom toolbar menus to expand what's available from the taskbar.